# Datagram sockets with Java client and Python server

Tags: java, android, python, udp, datagram

I am triying to comunicate 2 machines through datagram sockets but I guess I am missing something...
Machine A is runs an Android App (client)
Machine B is a server writen in Python

I can send a message from A to B without any problem, but A never gets the answer from B, the code is the following:

Client (Java) :

```
InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.0.10");
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
byte[] bufSent = "register".getBytes();
DatagramPacket dpSent = new DatagramPacket(bufSent,bufSent.length, serverAddr, 8088);
socket.send(dpSent);
byte[] bufRecv = new byte[1024];
DatagramPacket dpReceive = new DatagramPacket(bufRecv, bufRecv.length);
socket.receive(dpReceive);
String serverMessage = new String(dpReceive.getData(), 0, dpReceive.getLength());
Log.v(LOGTAG, "Received " + serverMessage);
```

Server (Python):

```
import socket
UDP_IP_DEST = "10.0.0.11"
UDP_IP = "10.0.0.10"
UDP_PORT = 8088

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    if data:
        print "received message:", data
        sock.sendto("I got the message", (UDP_IP_DEST, UDP_PORT))
```

Does anyone see where is the mistake? The point is that I have tried to send the answer to another machine instead of the mobile and it works fine.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with receiving, here's some code we use in our app for Datagrams modified with your values, you can see we do a few things differently in the socket set up. mSocket is just a private DatagramSocket member variable. Give it a try. I think you might need to bind, and possible set the reuse address flag.

```
try
{
    mSocket = new DatagramSocket(null);
    mSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
    mSocket.setBroadcast(false);
    mSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(8088));
    //Set a 1.5 second timeout for the coming receive calls
    mSocket.setSoTimeout(1500);

    String data = "myData";
    DatagramPacket udpPacket = new DatagramPacket(data.getBytes(), data.length(), InetAddress.getByName("10.0.0.10"), 8088);
    mSocket.send(udpPacket);

    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    DatagramPacket recvPacket = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
    mSocket.receive(recvPacket);

    String response = new String(recvPacket.getData());
} 
catch (SocketException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (UnknownHostException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```